# How should I patch drupal core to Calendar Systems module work thoroughly?

Tags: 7, datetime

After installation [Calendar Systems](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar_systems) module, I get a message in **status report** section that Its
require to patch drupal core to work fully.
Please see below image:

[image]

Comment: To apply the patch that comes with the module on "/includes/common.inc" file
You can find the patch in module's folder at patch/core_format_date_alter.patch
If you don't know how to apply a patch, follow the instruction here : http://drupal.org/patch/apply